# Animated TV show about a vampire with extra long teeth

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, vampire

I’m looking for title of an animated series with very short episodes about a vampire who had extra long teeth down to his ankles.

He lived alone in a castle and would always be unsuccessful at hunting, like inspector Clouseau in the *Pink Panther* cartoons; he would always bumble things. There was no dialogue, and it might be a European show that was.

I thought it was called *Victor*, but I can’t find any info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Ernest the Vampire* (1988)?

From [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_le_vampire), translated from French:

> Ernest Le Vampire is a French animated television series in 117 episodes of 2 minutes and 30 seconds. [...]
>
> Ernest is a clumsy but creative vampire. All sorts of misadventures happen to him in his castle. He lives in the company of a dragon, a bat, mice and other visitors ...

Note his chest-length teeth:

---

Found with the Google query `dessin animé vampire canines chevilles` (`cartoon vampire canines ankles`) which brought up [this list of vampire cartoons](https://www.senscritique.com/liste/Vampires_vous_avez_dit_vampires_dessins_animes/60436).